# TclError: unknown option "-Y"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to establish buttons (using Tkinter) on objects in a class. But when I do, it gives me the above error: `TclError: unknown option "-Y"`
Here's the chunk of code:

It's a method for objects in class Hex

```
def New(self,piece):
        if piece=='pawn':
            self.button= Tkinter.Button(root,text="P")
            self.button.place(X=self.X,Y=self.Y)
```

That last line is the one the errors are pointed toward, but the message also gives me a chunk of code that I believe is from the Tkinter.Button function:

```
   1917           self.tk.call(
   1918               ('place', 'configure', self._w)
-> 1919               + self._options(cnf, kw))
   1920     place = configure = config = place_configure
   1921     def place_forget(self)
```

Does anyone know more about what the problem is, or what I can do to fix it?

edit: I know I haven't added a command to the button yet, I haven't gotten there yet.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments need to be in lowercase:

```
self.button.place(x=self.X, y=self.Y)
```

You should apply that PEP 8 convention in your code, too, including lowercasing your method name and attributes.

Comment: Thanks TidB, you were right and it's working now. Yeah, my conventions aren't very good.